# Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string | number | boolean; }'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export interface BackendParameters {
  [key: string]: { [key: string]: string | boolean | number };
}

var param: BackendParameters = { par1: 2 } // error

var x: BackendParameters = { s: 1, 'x': 2 } // error
```

I get the error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string | number | boolean; }'

What is the difference between these two types?
How can I make interface for key-value pair object? The object could have many properties e.g  `let foo = {boo1:2,boo2:2}`

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code and the error **as text** to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The correct typing should be

```js
const x: BackendParameters = { someKey: { someOtherKey: 'some value' } }
```

If you don't want that, then your interface should be

```js
interface BackendParameters {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're look for

```
const x: BackendParameters = Record<string, string | number | boolean>
```

This allows any string key.